# Center buttons on responsive website

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a responsive website, on one of the pages I have 2 buttons, they are next to each other when the screen size is wide enough to fit both buttons, when the page is made smaller (i.e for a smartphone) then the second button (right) goes below the first. This works fine.

However when the buttons are one above the other they are positioned on the left, I would like to center them.

I have based it on this: http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/puA72/2/

Here is a JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kg2grant/

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="button-wrapper">

<div class="fiftyLEFT" ><button type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" name="submit_button"><span>Search</span></button></div>

<div class="fiftyRIGHT"><button onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" class="submit" style="font-size: 22px; width: 500px" value="show" name="show_button">Google</button></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
button.submit {
  border: none; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #52A1DD 50%, #53A2DE 100%);
  border-radius: 100px; 
  max-width: 90%; 
  margin-right: 5%; 
  padding: 8px 10px;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  }

button.submit:hover {
  color: #3193e9; 
  background: #fff;
  }

button.submit {
  width: calc(.5px + 50vw);
  }

button.submit img: hover {
  background-color: #C37500;
  opacity:0.7 !important;
  filter:alpha(opacity=70) !important;
  }

.button-wrapper
{
    width:100%;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 3px solid black
}

.button-wrapper > .fiftyLEFT
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    min-width:50px
}

.button-wrapper > .fiftyRIGHT
{
    min-width:400px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    white-space: nowrap;   
}
```

I have tried many things to like `margin 0 auto` and adding another container however had no luck! Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the display to `flex` and achieve what you want by using `@media` query.

Forked jsFiddle with the behavior needed: https://jsfiddle.net/o1gpcLcr/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove the float left property to do the margin auto.

```
.button-wrapper > .fiftyLEFT {
    width: 50%;
    /* float: left; */
    min-width: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.button-wrapper > .fiftyRIGHT {
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 50%;
    /* float: left; */
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Then do the float left on larger screens with @media (min-width: 768px), or wherever you want it to break.

Answer (score 0):

Using float makes margin auto behave strangely because the floated element have been removed from the regular flow of content. If you remove `float: left` from your last two CSS rules and declare `margin: auto`, it should work.

Alternatively, you can remove `float: left`, and then add

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

to your .button-wrapper rule. Using flexbox has the same effect as margin auto, but may make other changes and additions easier later in development.
To learn more about flexbox, check out https://flexbox.io for some great video tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use CSS media queries, with more of a 'mobile-first' approach.

Make the buttons width: 100% by default and then use @media (min-width: 768px) {...} to change the width to 50%.

I've made some changes to your code:

```css
button.submit {
  border: none; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #52A1DD 50%, #53A2DE 100%);
  border-radius: 100px; 
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

button.submit:hover {
  color: #3193e9; 
  background: #fff;
}

button.submit img: hover {
  background-color: #C37500;
  opacity:0.7 !important;
  filter:alpha(opacity=70) !important;
}

.button-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 3px solid black
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  button {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap; 
  }
}
```

```html
            <div class="button-wrapper">

            <div class="button" ><button type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" name="submit_button"><span>Search</span></button></div>

            <div class="button"><button onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" class="submit" value="show" name="show_button">Google</button></div>
            
            </div>
```